# Question about @property and @synthesize

Tags: ios4, properties, synthesizer

Usually we have codes like these

```
@interface TestAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@synthesize window;
```

And also second version

```
@interface TestAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
      UIWindow *_window;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@synthesize window = _window;
```

Quetions are

> - what is the big difference ? Which better ? and Why ?
> - For first version, Why what is the default attribute member of window ,which is _window in second version. Does that KVC or KVO work inside ?

Answer (score 1):

in the default instance it is the same as

```
@interface TestAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
      UIWindow *window;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@synthesize window = window;
```

which would actually not need an Assignment on the synthesize. and would probably generate an error.

This is the normal way that I do it.

```
@interface TestAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
      UIWindow *window;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@synthesize window;
```

I explicitly declare the Instance Variable

```
UIWindow *window;
```

so that I know it is there, (they are generally all right next to each other.)

and I separate them by the ones I retain and the ones I dont. So that I know to release them in my dealloc method

Comment: yes,I know that. I want to deep to understand some details inside.

Comment: ok well it is my understanding that @property and @synthesize are just shorthand.  @property is instructions on how you want the property @synthesized. observers and the like are a little different. I found this tho [KVC and KVO](http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/cocoa/how-cocoa-bindings-work-via-kvc-and-kvo) perhaps it will help

Comment: thanks again. Can you explain the first case ( without attribute window declaration inside ) , what happen inside ? because we do not have instance member "window" declared inside, how to invoke set/get ?

Comment: perhaps a better idea would be to give you a good place to get a lot more info... In ITunes U you can search for stanford iphone.. or you can view the video on properties here [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A79t7CVx_T0](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A79t7CVx_T0)